# Find Data Values of Blanks in Source Code in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

This is homework, so I'm just looking for a nudge forward.

I have a compiled C program and the source code with some blanks in it. My task is to find the "secret" values with GDB as an introduction to GDB. I have been working at this for a few hours and keep going in circles.

This is my give source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int gfoo = ;//secret 1
int main()
{
  static int sfoo;
  int lfoo;
  int *dfoo = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int));
  sfoo = ;//secret 2
  lfoo = ;//secret 3
  *dfoo = ;//secret 4
  return sfoo + lfoo + gfoo + *dfoo;
}
```

So far, I have opened the executable in GDB. Then I open assembly with

```
(gdb) layout asm
```

Then i set a break at main and run it. Then I can print the value of "gfoo" since it is global (p gfoo), but can't step to a point in the program where any of the other "secret" values are accessible. help?

Comment: as it stands this code will not compile, i believe you're supposed to give each of the "blanks" a random value and then show how you can access them in gdb

Comment: The code is already compiled with values in the blanks. I need to find what the values are in the compiled file with GDB. I just found the value of "gfoo" by running it in GDB, then typing "p/x gfoo" and got back "0xdeadbeef." However, I can't find the values of the local variables.

Comment: How do I find the location of return() if GDB cannot see the source?

Comment: I have been trying this and it seems to either find an infinite loop or it is taking a very long time to step all the way to the point where I can view the locals.

Comment: I assume your executable isn't built with debug symbols? Look for movl instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own version of the given code but put in known values for the variables. Then run gdb, type `layout asm` and find `movl` and your assigned values. Notice the pattern. Then load your executable with unknown values and view the asm layout. The pattern will be the same. Write down the values.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int gfoo = 1;//secret 1
int main()
{
  static int sfoo;
  int lfoo;
  int *dfoo = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int));
  sfoo = 2;//secret 2
  lfoo = 3;//secret 3
  *dfoo = 4;//secret 4
  return sfoo + lfoo + gfoo + *dfoo;
}


   ¦0x4004d8 <main+1>       mov    %rsp,%rbp                                                                                                                                                                                     ¦
   ¦0x4004db <main+4>       sub    $0x10,%rsp                                                                                                                                                                                    ¦
   ¦0x4004df <main+8>       mov    $0x4,%edi                                                                                                                                                                                     ¦
   ¦0x4004e4 <main+13>      callq  0x4003f0 <malloc@plt>                                                                                                                                                                         ¦
   ¦0x4004e9 <main+18>      mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)                                                                                                                                                                               ¦
   ¦0x4004ed <main+22>      movl   $0x2,0x200b35(%rip)        # 0x60102c <sfoo.2366>                                                                                                                                             ¦
   ¦0x4004f7 <main+32>      movl   $0x3,-0xc(%rbp)                                                                                                                                                                               ¦
   ¦0x4004fe <main+39>      mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                                                                                               ¦
   ¦0x400502 <main+43>      movl   $0x4,(%rax)                                                                                                                                                                                   ¦
   ¦0x400508 <main+49>      mov    0x200b1e(%rip),%edx        # 0x60102c <sfoo.2366>                                                                                                                                             ¦
   ¦0x40050e <main+55>      mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax                                                                                                                                                                               ¦
   ¦0x400511 <main+58>      add    %eax,%edx                                                                                                                                                                                     ¦
   ¦0x400513 <main+60>      mov    0x200b0b(%rip),%eax        # 0x601024 <gfoo>                                                                                                                                                  ¦
   ¦0x400519 <main+66>      add    %eax,%edx                                                                                                                                                                                     ¦
   ¦0x40051b <main+68>      mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                                                                                               ¦
   ¦0x40051f <main+72>      mov    (%rax),%eax
```

Notice the `movl` instructions.

When you run the code, you'll see something like this:

```
[Inferior 1 (process 49611) exited with code 012]
```

012 is octal or 10 decimal. You can use that value to validate your answers.